# Function call not working from another callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I'm wondering why this `scrollingView` function does not work with this code.

From `tableView`, both view controllers are in the same class. When I set the execution of `scrollView` `setContentOffset` in another button in my primary view, it's working like a charm. Can anyone explain me this?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSInteger currentRow = indexPath.row;
    if (currentRow == 0) {
        [_back sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 1450) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it doing and what are you trying to make it do?

Comment: It's a tableView raw, and when it's cliecked, it goes back to the main view, and should scroll content in webview to 1450 position.

Comment: Is the _webview in your main view or in the same view as the table view?

Answer (score 1):

You should set a breakpoint or added a log statement to confirm that your code is being executed.

If you forgot to wire up the delegate link to your table view then the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method won't be called at all.

Next, make sure that _back and _webView are not nil. (If you used a breakpoint then you could use the debugger to verify these things. If you're using a log statement, log those values of those 2 variables.

When code doesn't work, the first thing to do is check your outlet, action, and delegate links.